# Tomcat is running in eclipe but can't access http://localhost:8080/ or can't run my webapp

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat9

I am facing a peculiar problem, i can see my tomcat is running but then when i run http://localhost:8080/, i am getting error.

I have seen lots of solution which sort of tries to resolve this issue but i am unable to solve it.

Below screen print shows, that there is nothing running on port 8080 when tomcat is stopped.

[image]

Indeed my tomcat is stopped and i can't connect to localhost:8080 from browser.

[image]

[image]

Now, i will start my tomcat inside eclipse from "Servers" project and by right clicking on "Servers" tab.
Below screen print you can see Tomcat v9.0 is started.

[image]

Now this can be verified from seeing the process running on port 8080 from command line.

[image]

But when i run http://localhost:8080 in browser i get error which say like below :-

**Message** The requested resource [/] is not available

**Description** The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

[image]

Now you will be interested to see my config page for my tomcat, below is what i have.

[image]

someone even suggested to change server location to "Use Tomcat installation ...." but for me it's not highlighted.

I am struck on this from last 2 days, can someone help?

Comment: Remove this server and then try adding a server using the tomcat downloaded from apache. i.e. server path should point to your local folder of tomcat in the tomcat config. Then the option to select "Use Tomcat Installation" will be enabled. Select that, save and start.

Comment: You need to access `http://localhost:8080/appname`, where `appname` is by default the Eclipse project name. Check the _"Modules"_ tab of Eclipse's server configuration.